# What is the purpose of the SupportsUserInfo/PutUserInfo in WOPI

Tags: ms-wopi

What is the purpose of operation `PutUserInfo` (given `SupportsUserInfo=true`) in [WOPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/putuserinfo)?

How do I see it in real life (not in test), i.e. when the Office Online server calls it, and what is meaning of the argument passed in? I have read the documents, but it does not explain that. What feature would I miss if I say `SupportsUserInfo=false`?